# Does "use X, Y, or Z" mean use *one of* or *all of* the options?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, construction

This is the text supposedly providing the parameters for creating acceptable usernames for a particular website:

> The username is case sensitive. Choose a username that is 6-74 characters long and must contain a lowercase or capital letter, a number, or one of these symbols _.@/-

In other words:
A username for this site must consist of from 6 to 74 characters **and**
  must contain **one** of the following:

```
 -any upper or lower case letter
 -any 6 to 74 digit number 
 -any one of the following symbols _.@/-
```

Therefore, any of the following should be acceptable usernames:

- @@@@@@
- 99999999999999999999999999999999999
- /////......///
- dar2zen

None of those, however, are actually accepted by the website. Therefore, the parameters, as stated, do not state what they mean to state. What they do mean to state is not clear. When the system rejects a username, no feedback on what requirement that username is failing to meet is given.

**My question here is whether I am correct in believing that the username requirements, as written, state what I say they state.**

Comment: I realize that my title is not exactly appropriate. I would love it if someone could provide a better one.

Comment: You are quite correct in your interpretation. Since even _dar2zen_ does not work, I can only assume that ‘or’ here is an error, and that it should have said ‘and’. Only a requirement for _both_ a letter (upper- or lowercase), _and_ a number, _and_ one of those symbols would make that an invalid combination.

Comment: Not only does dar2zen* not work, but Dar2zen **does**. Which adds to the complication. Now, it could be that dar2zen was already taken, though I find that highly unlikely.

Comment: Probably the 6-74 characters refers to alphanumeric characters, where in addition to numbers and lowercase letters, you have to have either a capital letter or a special character.  Looks like the instructions are just flat out wrong.  BTW, I hope you aren't using any of these passwords anywhere on the internet, since that's where they are now posted  :)

Comment: @trpt4him Unfortunately, since the instructions don't say what they do mean, we can go on guessing. I've reported the issue to the site, but can't get a clarification of the actual requirements. And, remember, those are hypothetical usernames, not passwords. (And no, I'm not using them as passwords either!)

Comment: In case it matters, my criticism is of the mechanics of site itself (the sign-up credentials problem being only one of many), not the content.

Answer (score 2):

As written the instructions are rather unclear. The more appropriate way to write out these kinds of complicated instructions is to use a list of requirements:

> The username is case sensitive. Choose a username that satisfies **each** of the following requirements:
>
> - 6-74 characters long
> - contains at least one letter
> - contains at least one number
> - contains at least one of these symbols _.@/-

To answer your specific question, the paragraph is written as these instructions are often written and *does* explain the requirements but it does not do so unambiguously.

In short:

1. The paragraph is not strictly, technically correct (e.g. @@@@@@ is not a valid username)
2. The paragraph's *actual* meaning is clear in the sense that they convey the intended rules *in plain English* (albeit poorly) because users don't typically try to create usernames like @@@@@@ legitimately
3. The website should update their paragraph to be both technically correct (1) and convey the meaning in English (2)

Comment: +1 and I will add that the sentence is actually written rather clumsily. It should be either "a username that **is** X characters long **and contains** Y", or "the username **must be** X characters long **and contain** Y", but not the mix-and-matching of both we have here. We simply do not "choose a username that must be", that grates on the ears.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @RegDwigнt but didn't feel like proofing the entire thing since a list is much less ambiguous.

Comment: @MrHen I can't really see your point. It seems, rather, that requirements as defined in the paragraph are unambiguous. My complaint is that the requirements they defining are not the actual requirements for a valid username for the site. I agree that your list is far superior to the paragraph used. Also, please reread my specific question--the last sentence in the OP. I'm looking to designate a correct answer here, so I was hoping someone who's already answered could edit what they have. Thanks.

Comment: @sarah: Is my post not providing an adequate answer to your question? The last sentence is attempting to explicitly answer your question.

Comment: @MrHen, Hi. That was quick! I end the OP with, "My question here is whether I am correct in believing that the username requirements, as written, state what I say they state." So, I was attempting to find out if I was misreading the text that supposedly laid out the parameters. I was very frustrated trying to create a username for the site, and was pretty darn sure I was meeting the requirements as stated (unambiguously, I think--just inaccurate, seems to me), but wanted to check to see if I was misreading what was written.

Comment: Short version: The paragraph is poorly written and, therefore, you misinterpreted it as a strict, technical description when they were actually just guidelines hinting at the strict, technical description. I primarily blame the paragraph for the confusion but I *am* a little surprised at how much confusion resulted.

Comment: @MrHen Well, I'm not sure what you mean. If you're referring to my personal confusion--I was confused because I expect that the listed parameters for creating a username on a specific site **will** be the strict, technical description of the actual requirements, since that's all I have to go on for any given site. Why would a webmaster provide something **close to** the requirements?

Comment: @sarah: No idea but they apparently did... :) I wouldn't label your confusion unwarranted. You are correct that the listed parameters are not strictly, technically correct.

Comment: OK, now you've lost me completely. You said you found the confusion surprising, yet you say it's not unwarranted.

Comment: Also, I'm really not understanding your assertion that the username requirements, as presented, are "not strictly, technically" correct. Again, the parameters are presented using wording that does mean something specific. If, in fact, any username created using the parameters as stated were valid, then we might say that the list format would be more user-friendly, but I don't see how we could legitimately claim that the requirements were ambiguously stated. Aaarrghh! Not trying to be difficult here! Just trying to understand your points. Also, not exactly sure what ELU chat is, but...

Comment: No worries; you aren't being difficult. I added a summary to the answer; hopefully that will help clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

"or" means 'or".  As written any one of those categories would be valid, so:

> "000000000"

should be a valid password.

Since it is not, the definitions of the requirements of a password remains incomplete.

Apparently the commenters seem to be converging that the true rules are:

> 6 characters+ which can be letters, numbers and punctuation.
>
> Must contain three of the following: small letters, capital letters, numbers, and punctuation.

Comment: The commenters may or may not know what the site requirements for a username are. That's why the situation is so  frustrating to me. Since what they say is not what they mean, they may mean what it sort of seems logical to assume that they might have meant, but we have no way of knowing for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is correct. The question says or, so it basically gives you a choice between them.

Comment: What is the "it" that you are saying is correct? And to which question do you refer?